# Null Reference Exception when writing to custom class

Tags: arrays, vba, class

So I'm just starting to get into custom classes in VB and running into this error when I attempt to write. I tried to follow the teacher's example, but also wanted to get into some of the more advanced aspects of VB and tried to use an array within my classes, and well, things don't quite work.

Form1 class:

```
Dim mypt(7) As Point

Private Sub Create_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Create.Click
    PtSelect = Input()  'Returns an int
    mypt(PtSelect).mC(0) = CDec(IX.Text) 'Error here!
    mypt(PtSelect).mC(1) = CDec(IY.Text)
    mypt(PtSelect).mC(2) = CDec(IZ.Text)
End Sub
```

Point Class:

```
Public Class Point
Private c(2) As Decimal

Public Sub New(ByVal X As Decimal, ByVal Y As Decimal, ByVal Z As Decimal)
    c(0) = X
    c(1) = Y
    c(2) = Z
End Sub

Public Property mC(Val As Integer) As Decimal
    Get
        Return c(Val)
    End Get
    Set(value As Decimal)
        c(Val) = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Really just unsure what to do past this point, I've fiddled with everything that I could think may be it, but am unsure. My teacher did say that is was possible to use arrays within classes before I ran into the error and I'd like to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using class in Vb.net, it use the concept of pointer. This mean that each variable point to an object. So when you instantiate your array

```
 Dim mypt(7) As Point
```

it create an array of 8 pointer that each contains the value Nothing. You have to call the constructor of your class Point with

```
New Point(2,2,3)
```

and make the pointer in your array point to that object.

```
mypt(1) = New Point(2,2,3)
```

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

Got it working thanks to user Matriac! Only change I had to make was this:

```
    mypt(PtSelect).mC(0) = CDec(IX.Text) 'Error here!
    mypt(PtSelect).mC(1) = CDec(IY.Text)
    mypt(PtSelect).mC(2) = CDec(IZ.Text)
```

To this:

```
mypt(PtSelect) = New Point(CDec(IX.Text), CInt(IY.Text), CDec(IZ.Text))
```